# Templates and explicit specializations

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template

```
template<class T>
T maxn(T *, int);
```

and explicit specialization for `char*`

```
template<> char* maxn(char**, int);
```

And I want to add `const`,

```
T maxn(const T *, int);
```

but after adding const in explicit specialization there is an error.

```
template<>char* maxn<char*>(const char**, int);
```

Why? Who can explain to me?

> **P.S.** Sorry for my English.))

Comment: You get an error because it's *not* a specialization, but an overload instead. The `const` is a factor in the function signature that changes it from specialization to overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the parameter type `const T *`, `const` is qualified on `T`. Then for `char*` (the pointer to `char`) it should be `char* const` (`const` pointer to `char`), but not `const char*` (non-const pointer to `const` `char`).

```
template<class T>
T maxn(const T *, int);

template<>
char* maxn<char*>(char* const *, int);
//                      ~~~~~
```

Comment: This changes the original template so it won't accept pointers to non-const objects anymore.

Comment: @VTT What do you mean "change the original template"? Which part?

Comment: Original template was `maxn(T *, int);`, not `maxn(const T *, int);`

Comment: @VTT But OP said, "And I want to add const,..." After adding `const` OP got the errors, then OP asked how to solve it, I think.

Comment: yes, but i think it was supposed to be "to add const tp specialization"

Comment: @VTT Oh, but OP wrote sth like `const T*`, I suppose to be "add  const to primary template". (And function template doesn't support partial specialization..)

Comment: I want add const to the template too, no not only to specialization

Answer (score 2):

You should instantiate the method for `const char*`:

```
template<> const char* maxn<const char*>(const char**, int);
```

`template<>char* maxn<char*>(const char**, int);` doesn't correspond to

```
template<class T>
T maxn(T *, int);
```

signature, so you can't just add `const` to one parameter.